# Should this site split up into more specialized sites?

Tags: discussion, split-stack-overflow

The number of uncorrelated tags is exploding exponentially with the number of specific languages, their modules, add-ons and derivations, frameworks and IDEs.

When I review questions that I could answer, most questions fall out of scope because I never ever heard about this yet another fancy tool.

What can be done?

It is impossible to know about even a fraction of those, and this is what I think this site is suffering about.

Comment: This is what watched, and ignored, tags are for.

Comment: "When I review questions that I could answer" is your problem reviewing or answering? It is pretty straightforward to filter by tag if you are just looking for things to answer.

Comment: One site per [JavaScript library](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f)? The overhead of separate sites is probably too high.

Comment: I filter my reviewing to to the languages I claim some expertise in. If I see, for example `C++` and `yaft`, I'll read and then hit skip if I have questions about what's being asked. A lot of the time though I do know enough to be able to edit into better shape, approve/reject an edit, or vote for the plunger.

Comment: I removed all mentions of the OP's acronym, as that was clearly leading the conversation astray. Please let's focus on what is being actually discussed here.

Comment: [How do I use tags to find topics I'm interested in?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)

Answer (score 17):

Stack Exchange already has specialized sites, i.e. [WordPress Developers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) is one of them. You can find more at https://stackexchange.com/sites. Besides Stack Overflow, there are 181 sites, 76 of which are grouped in the technology category.

The number of "unrelated tags" doesn't warrant the need for a new site; what warrants the need for a new site is the existence of a community out there willing to use the Q&A model that found that the scope and workings of Stack Overflow not fit their needs and willing to define their scope and workings.

Once you find such a community, go to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com), learn about the new site proposal, prepare yourself, and create your new site proposal when you and your community be ready to fulfill the process on time.

Comment: Bingo; this is the core. The [list of dead and archived sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarea51.stackexchange.com+%22didn%27t+have+enough+activity+during+the+beta%22) is full of good topics with no people to rally behind them.

Comment: I might add my list of good topics that I'm interested in, but I haven't found a community that likes the Q&A model, among many other reasons :)

Comment: Q&A ain't for everything. As we've seen first hand, it makes a crappy help desk.

Comment: @zcoop98 interestingly, there's at least 3+ sites returned by that search that **are** actually now full sites